# backupninja: password outside config file

Tags: security, backup

I would like to use a `dup` rule in backupninja to make an encrypted remote backup. The configuration file format includes entries for the encryption and ftp password.

I would like to move them out of the configuration file, so that I can throw the config file inside a git repository for versioning without leaking my passwords.

Is there a simple way to do that?